# Wedge-like gaps at road intersections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, cartography, intersection, road

In ArcMap 10.3, I am making a map, which contains a road layer represented by dual lines. Unfortunately, at some intersection points, the lines are interrupted and tend to create wedge-like gaps (see red circles in figures below). I am struggling with it for quite a long time, but I still have not found any viable solution. One idea was to slightly change the position of the vertices at the intersection points. Indeed, it worked, but this approach is not very well suitable for the relatively large dataset (with numerous intersections) I have. Further, and more importantly, I don't want to disrupt the topology. Do you have any suggestions how to resolve this matter?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What geometry type do you use? Polygons?

Comment: No, I use polylines. Each street is composed of two lines of different width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens as a result of two of your symbology settings for the line - line caps and line joins. There are three choices for each, and you may have to experiment with combinations of each to see if you can get the desired effect. It may not be possible to get it completely clean because of how the lines are broken up. In such cases you might have to maintain two layers - an actual data layer and a 'cartographic' layer where you can dissolve lines based on street name or some other such criteria.

This topic is discussed in a series of Esri blog posts on [symbolizing roads with cased lines](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/11/28/symbolizing-roads-with-cased-line-symbols-part-1-of-3/).

Comment: I followed the second suggested procedure, i.e. I dissolved the lines based on their names/codes and now it looks fine. The problem was that the streets were originally composed of several consecutive lines and the gaps were created at their contacts.
Thank you for your helpful comment!